# Xamarin.forms how to Change the Nav Bar Color

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am trying to change the nav `BarBackgroundColor`  background color on portable class library project, so how to Change the Nav Bar Color on **Xamarin.Forms**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NavigationPage has a `BarBackgroundColor` property which you can set.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/

```
var nav = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage { Title = "Page" } );
nav.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: where i should do that ...it is static property ..could you please add some code ...I get Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor.get'

Comment: BarBackgroundColorProperty is a static backing property for the BarBackgroundColor property. Set BarBackgroundColor when you instantiate the NavigationPage.

Comment: so I recommend you guys to do it on App Class new ex:  NavigationPage(new LoginPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.Green }

Comment: I have added a code snippet.

Comment: @Paul I would argue that your code is not working .. You can't change BarBackgroundColor after intialization bec. it is defined as `readonly`. so `nav.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;` wouldn't work. However Mark Darwish code is the correct one .. So if my argument is true then please edit your main answer

Comment: this is for a single page. is there a solution to override for all available pages