# Xamarin Form Navigation Bar Color to be changed in Windows platform

Tags: windows, xamarin, colors, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I am using a Portable Xamarin form solution to create an Application that will work in IOS, Android and Windows.We are facing a problem in setting the background color of the Navigation Bar. BarBackground color is not working so We tried to change the colors in each Platform but couldn't do it in Windows.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062495/xamarin-forms-how-to-change-the-nav-bar-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
You are using Xamarin.forms. So, change the constructor of App.Xaml.cs in your PCL.

public App()
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1())
    {
        BarBackgroundColor = Color.Gray
    };
}
```